# Not sure where to put logic loop [java]

Tags: java, element, do-while

I'm currently trying to build a small program for school. If you click on a checkbox it should show other elements. I learned in python that you need a while loop because the program needs to go over the same lines again where you check if the box is checked but if i put a loop the whole program won't start. I don't understand why.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class test extends JFrame {
    private JCheckBox moredetailscheck;
    private JTextField inputfielduser;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test venster = new test();
        venster.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        venster.setSize(800, 600);
        venster.setVisible(true);
        venster.setTitle("true");
        venster.setResizable(false);
    }
    public test() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        moredetailscheck = new JCheckBox("checkbox", false);
        add(moredetailscheck);
        inputfielduser = new JTextField(15);
        while(true) {   // you want to let the program keep going over these lines
        if(moredetailscheck.isSelected()) {
            add(inputfielduser);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, get rid of that `while (true)` loop. It has no business being in an event-driven program. Next, learn about how to listen for events using appropriate listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you click on a checkbox it should show other elements.

So, you would attach a listener to the JCheckBox, here an ItemListener, that responds when the state of the JCheckBox changes.

> I learned in python that you need a while loop because the program needs to go over the same lines again where you check if the box is checked

This is called "polling" and is needed for linear console programs where you need to continually obtain input from the user, again in a "linear" fashion. In these types of programs, you the programmer are in complete control over program code flow, but that's not what you want here.

> but if i put a loop the whole program won't start. I don't understand why.

That's because you're now using an event-driven GUI library, there the Swing library, and by calling a `while (true)` loop on the event thread, you completely block it, rendering your GUI useless. Your program is starting, but it can't construct the GUI, draw itself or listen for events.

Solution:

- Get rid of the `while (true)` loop. Again, it is useful for simple console programs but not in this situation.
- Add an ItemListener to your JCheckBox. You can find out how to do that in the [check box tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- Don't keep adding items to your GUI. Use a CardLayout to swap views. The tutorial can be found here: [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).
- Or even better, have all the GUI items on the GUI at startup, but use the JCheckBox state to enable/disable an item.

As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCheckBox extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JCheckBox moreDetailsCheck = new JCheckBox("More Details", false);
    private JTextField inputFieldUser = new JTextField(15);

    public TestCheckBox() {
        inputFieldUser.setEnabled(false);
        add(moreDetailsCheck);
        add(inputFieldUser);

        // add a listener to the JCheckBox
        moreDetailsCheck.addItemListener(e -> {
            // if checkbox selected, enable the text field. else disable it
            inputFieldUser.setEnabled(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TestCheckBox mainPanel = new TestCheckBox();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test CheckBox");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the AWT starts a thread to handle events automatically; you just let `main` finish and the program keeps running anyway until you call `System.exit`.  You do need event handlers, though, for which any number of tutorials exist.

(Incidentally, your infinite loop comes before even showing your `JFrame`.)